# openlayers. Get Data from feature when clicked (Modify events)

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I have a folowing test case and this issue: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3008

http://jsfiddle.net/mindsupport/gyumL4q6/3/

When i drag it or click, there is no property oData in object. Where is it ? But on  change listener work great.